# I get a “No root file system is defined” error when choosing a partition to install Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, partition, system-installation

When I select a partition to install Linux I get that error. I want to dual-boot Windows with Linux.

I’ve selected ext4 and `/boot` and that, so I don’t know what’s wrong.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like all partitions you have for Mint are `/boot`, right?

There MUST be a partition for `/` (the root).  And if you have EFI (which you probably have), you'll also need to make sure that the EFI System Partition (ESP) gets mounted as `/boot/efi`.   (You actually don't need a `/boot` partition on, unless your computer is extremely old.)

The easiest way should be to choose guided partitioning and "install Mint alongside Windows" or whatever that option is called.  But if you choose to do it manually, make very sure that you don't "format" the ESP but "keep existing data".